# OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I am using opencv for android. I tried to init opencv with static initialization. I followed the doucument from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization)

Now i got a problem.

```
01-01 20:01:46.156: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): Trying to get library list
01-01 20:01:46.156: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): loadLibrary opencvinfo
01-01 20:01:46.156: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): /vendor/lib:/system/lib
01-01 20:01:46.156: E/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
01-01 20:01:46.156: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): Library list: ""
01-01 20:01:46.156: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): First attempt to load libs
01-01 20:01:46.157: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): Trying to init OpenCV libs
01-01 20:01:46.157: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): Trying to load library opencv_java
01-01 20:01:46.177: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): OpenCV libs init was ok!
01-01 20:01:46.177: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): First attempt to load libs is OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logcat "01-01 20:01:46.177: D/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): OpenCV libs init was ok!"` it mean you opencv libs has success load ,and what's your problem?

Comment: thank your .the problem is :logcat E/OpenCV/StaticHelper(14057): OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV and the app can not start.Now i fixed this problem by pushing the lib(libopencv_java.so) into system/lib folder on the phone.

Comment: Where is ` lib(libopencv_java.so)`? I only found libopencv_java.so, I presume they are both the same?

Comment: Is this an answer? How does this solve your problem? I have the same identical problem, and I dont see any solution here

Comment: I have this problem as well, it says that it was loaded OK, but it doesn't work . Only black screen appears. I have this problem only on Samsung Galaxy S3. Works without any problems on HTC Desire X or OnePlusOne.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occurs when the  phone does not supporting OpenCV version 2.x. If this is the case, The emulator would be working fine.

Switch to OpenCV version 3.x, where it works fine.