# Processing an Android camera-intent Bitmap image in OpenCV (needs conversion to Mat object)?

Tags: android, opencv, bitmap, android-ndk, android-camera-intent

I am trying to process a bmp image obtained from Android's camera intent through the following steps:

1. Obtain `bmp` image from intent
2. Convert `bmp` image to `Mat` object for OpenCV processing **(problem starts here)**
3. Do needed OpenCV processing (through sending `Mat` object, *obj*, as *obj*`.getNativeObjAddr()` to native processing, or perform it locally in java).
4. Convert `Mat` object back to `bmp`

The problem is indeed not novel. I have found countless similar questions online, none of which seem to resolve the situation however.

### Results (problem)

The intention is to display the processed image (that undergoes the above 4 steps) in an `ImageView` object. After running, the ImageView however remains unchanged and logcat emits the following warning on reaching the line calling `Utils.bitmapToMat()`

```
 W/System.err(3872): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mat == null
```

### Code

Below is the code's outline that is used in the `onActivityResult` method (`resultant_bmp` is the acquired bmp from the camera intent. It displays successfully on its own).
`filePath` is the file path, name and extension included, of `resultant_bmp`.

The first 3 lines following the starting `if` condition are from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-opencv/maGpOvyIqp0), where its use seems to work fine in the mentioned question.

```
Bitmap resultant_bmp /*image from camera*/,   
       bmp /*image after opencv processing*/;
Mat rgb_img, gray_img;      

if (OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) { 

     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
     resultant_bmp= BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);

     /****************** Problem starts HERE ******************
     Last point reachable before Logcat states:
       W/System.err(4460):java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mat == null   

     After this point, the program doesn't crash, but expected results 
       in the imageView (last line of code) do not result.
     **********************************************************/  

     Utils.bitmapToMat(resultant_bmp, rgb_img);                                 
     Imgproc.cvtColor(rgb_img, gray_img, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY); 

     /*Do opencv processing (on gray_img) here*/

     Utils.matToBitmap(gray_img, bmp);

     imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);

}
```

### Previous attempts& research

- I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042767/opencv-error-cannot-load-info-library-for-opencv?rq=1) and tried, as recommended, to push the file `libopencv_java.so` to `system/lib` on the device, using adb in command line and received the error:

`failed to copy 'libopencv_java.so' to 'system/lib/libopencv_java.so': Read-only file system`

- [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454542/android-opencv-converting-mat-to-grayscale-with-using-mattobitmap-bitmaptomat) question considers the same problem domain in the current question; the code provided above follows a similar pattern as that suggested there, which still doesn't work.
- Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10869291/1446598) answer (as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042767/opencv-error-cannot-load-info-library-for-opencv?rq=1) aforementioned one), I added the following lines to the code:

`System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");

System.loadLibrary("libopencv_java");`

- I have added the OpenCV library to the project properties; as well as the NDKROOT variable indicating where the NDK root path lies, as explained further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14527852/1446598).
- I've tried the image processing required (in step 3 above) in another working sample of OpenCV's, so the problem definitely lies within **step 2** (above); conversion of a `bmp` to a `Mat` object.

There should be a simple solution around this, but I cannot seem to find it. Help would be much appreciated if possible.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialized your mat variable ? I couldnt find it in provided code.

Add this before you try to convert to mat.

```
Mat rgb_img = new Mat();
```

Comment: Thank you very much; this is indeed the problem. No, I haven't.
Adding this line will get through logcat, but wouldn't display in the imageView however (regarding step 4 not 2). To do so; the following line must also be added (as done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454542/android-opencv-converting-mat-to-grayscale-with-using-mattobitmap-bitmaptomat)):
`bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(gray_img.cols(), gray_img.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);`
It now works.